# wcf service with transport security

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, wcf-client

I've been struggling with following since few days. Please help me. I'm using XP machine with .Net 3.5. I was following this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729789.aspx. I created a certificate using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733813(v=vs.90).aspx and imported the root certificate in the Certificate(Local Computer) > Trusted Root Certification Authorities > Certificates and other one in the Certificate(Local Computer) > Personal > Certificates. I've self hosted service. The hosing code is

```
        ServiceHost svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService.CalculatorService), new  Uri("https://localhost:8012/CalculatorService"));           
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
        if (smb == null)
            smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
        svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
        svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
            MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpsBinding(),
            "mex");
        WSHttpBinding b = new WSHttpBinding();
        b.Security.Mode= SecurityMode.Transport;
        b.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None; 
        svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(CalculatorService.ICalculator),b , "");
        svcHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "SignedByCA");
        svcHost.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
        svcHost.Close();
```

When I try to add reference in the client I get the following error.

> There was an error downloading 'https://localhost:8012/CalculatorService/mex'.
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>   Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://localhost:8012/CalculatorService/mex'.
>   An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://localhost:8012/CalculatorService/mex. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>   Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

I think I've tried all possible ways. Now, I've no clue. Please help me. You're my final resource.

Comment: if you disable the ssl are you able to do the add reference?

Comment: yes, if I disable SSL I can add reference.

Comment: so at least this should not block you - continue to develop based on the non-ssl certificate. in mmc when you double click the certificate does it say it is trusted or not (should have a red x icon or soemthing).

Comment: There is no red icon in the certificate. Both, root and child certificates are fine.

Comment: note sure, maybe the problem is that the certificate is issues to SomeEntity but the actual wsdl is on localhost. VS probably expects the certificate to be with CN=localhost